# How can i perform a calculation for each field of a HTML table generated with PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following code which succesfully generates a HTML table of items and the amount:

```
<?php
$str = shell_exec( "command'" );
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str); //break each line
$arr = array_chunk($arr,2); // group each pair
foreach($arr as $e)
    $res[$e[0]] = $e[1]; // group each pair as key and value
?>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table alt-pagination trading-wrapper">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        item:
                                    </th>
                                <th>
                                        Amount:
                                    </th>
                <th>
                                        x
                                    </th>
                <th>
                                        x
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <?php foreach($res as $item => $amount)
echo '<tr class="1"><td class="1"><i class="1"></i>'. $item . '</td><td class="2">' . $amount . '</td><td class="3"></td>
<td class="4">x</td></tr>'; ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

I would like to add a third column in the table named price (USD), to get the price of the item i need to run file_get_contents on a file, then multiply the returned value by 10 then echo the output. The item variable is used in the file name to find the correct file.
I have attempted this using the code below and it formula is correct, however i can not seem to find the correct format to implement the strings within the current code:

```
        <?php foreach($res as $item => $amount)
echo '<tr class="1"><td class="1"><i class="cc '. $item . ' warning"></i>'. $item . '</td><td class="price">' . $amount . '</td><td class="price">'$command = '/var/www/html/prices/'.$item.'.txt'; $price1 = file_get_contents("$command"); $price = $price1 * 10; echo $price;'</td>
<td class="price">x</td></tr>'; ?>
```

I receive the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in file.php on line 160
```

How can i correctly implement this?

Comment: There's multiple issues wtih your code, which would be more obvious if you used line breaks and indentation. @Pankaj's answer addresses most of the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please fix your code according to this-

```
<?php foreach($res as $item => $amount) { ?>
<tr class="1">
    <td class="1">
         <i class="cc <?php echo $item; ?> warning"></i> <?php echo $item; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="price"><?php echo $amount; ?></td>
    <td class="price">
       <?php
       $command = '/var/www/html/prices/'.$item.'.txt';
       $price1 = file_get_contents($command);
       $price = (float) $price1 * 10;
       echo $price;
       ?>
    </td>
    <td class="price">x</td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I have fixed the improperly closed statements and made the code a bit clear.